# reinforce + that-clause

Tags: word-usage, verbs, objects, complementation

I don't know if it's okay for the verb "reinforce" to take a that-clause as an object. Is it a new usage? Following learners' dictionaries, I'd have expected a noun object, such as "the idea that ..."

> There are two problems with distracting with media: It takes away an opportunity to teach the child about how to respond to difficult emotions, and it can **reinforce** that big displays of their difficult emotions are effective ways to get what they want, Radesky said.

https://edition.cnn.com/2022/12/12/health/tantrum-distraction-screens-parenting-wellness/index.html

Comment: It is typical speech omission: reinforce the fact that big displays etc.

Comment: Asking about grammar by providing TV interview text is not a great idea. Spoken and written language are not the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie It is not a direct quote. Paraphrases are allowed in indirect quotes.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's direct or indirect.

Comment: @Lambie It does. In indirect quotes, the writer is supposed to wrtie in error-free English.

Comment: In indirect speech, the writer has more freedom and is not limited to using every word someone says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Reinforce' is a transitive verb, that is, one that uses a direct object (a thing, a noun). For example you could say that distracting with media can reinforce *the idea*, *the belief*, or *the notion* that big displays... etc.

Comment: Do you therefore think CNN's sentence is not good?

Comment: @Apollyon - as Lambie comments above, it contains an omission.

Comment: My question is whether this omission is widely acceptable.

Comment: @Apollyon - I do not like it and would not write or speak like that. I have noticed similar errors in mainly American texts.

Comment: The entire article has quotes around all the statements by people who were interviewed except this one. So, *that implies that the writer and/or editor just missed the quote marks* (inverted commas in BrE). It is very unlikely that this was indirect speech. Indirect speech would not have a comma like that. There are many people interviewed. In speech it is fine and has nothing to do with American "texts". Spoken language in British English has just as many oddities, innit?

Comment: @Lambie In indirect speech, the quoted material could be followed by a comma: "When the reporting clause comes after the reported clause, we use a comma to separate the two parts" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech_2

Comment: Cambridge offers this example: Nobody had gone in or out during the previous hour, he informed us.

Comment: @Lambie The quote in the OP is by no means the only one without quotation marks in the CNN article. See this example: The study lines up with the current recommendations from the American Academy of Pediatrics, the American Academy of Child and Adolescent Psychiatry and the World Health Organization that children ages 2 to 5 should have very limited screen time, said Dr. Joyce Harrison, associate professor of psychiatry and behavioral sciences at Johns Hopkins School of Medicine in Baltimore.

Comment: And these: It can be helpful for caregivers to help kids name their emotions and offer solutions when they are responding inappropriately to those feelings, she said.

That could mean identifying that the hitting and crying is because a child misses their mom and then offering a hug and to go get a photo of her, Radesky added.

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, when he said, he added etc, comes at the end, there is a comma. However, what comes before it can mostly just be copied down as the speaker said it.

Comment: Who knows? What comes before the comma may also have been the writer's paraphrase of what the speaker actually said.